# PHP Memory Shortage? Or?

Tags: php

I've got a web server running IIS7 and I just updated to PHP 5.3. I have two sites that seem to run fine, and they both use some small degree of PHP. The revision I am currently testing on this server, presumably uses much... much more.

The problem I am encountering is that on my testing server ( a local XAMPP installation ), my page loads fine. When I push this to my server and hit the page in my browser, I get the following:

```
Id ) return true; } return false; } public static function PrintSelector($SelectionArray) { if( !isset($SelectionArray)) { Page::WriteLine("
No selections are available.

"); } else { $FoundViewer = false; foreach($SelectionArray as $Selection) { if( $Selection->IsViewing()) { $ViewerSelection = $Selection; $FoundViewer = true; } } if( $FoundViewer ) { Page::WriteLine("Show / Hide " . get_class($Selection) . " Selections"); $ViewerSelection->PrintOverview(); Page::WriteLine("
"); } Page::WriteLine("\n"); foreach($SelectionArray as $Selection) if( $Selection->IsSelectable() && !$Selection->IsViewing()) $Selection->PrintSelection(); Page::WriteLine("
\n"); if( $FoundViewer ) Page::WriteLine("
"); } } } ?>
```

Which is just a bit of the underlying code for my new site.

Upon further investigation, I run down to one of my other sites and get this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />

<title>AGP Credential Manager</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript">

function submitPageForm()

{

  document.forms["pageForm"].submit();

}



function submitForm(formName)

{

  document.forms[formName].submit();

}

</script>



<script language="javascript">

  function toggleDiv(divid){

    if(document.getElementById(divid).style.display == 'none'){

      document.getElementById(divid).style.display = 'block';

    }else{

      document.getElementById(divid).style.display = 'none';

    }

  }

</script></head>

<body>

<div id="wrap">

    <div class="header">

        <!-- TITLE -->

        <h1><a href="#">AGP Credential Manager</a></h1>

        <!-- END TITLE -->

    </div>

    <div id="nav">

        <ul>    

            <!-- MENU -->
```

In the source code. And as I'm sure you can presume, not much for my front-end. It seems as if the PHP starts executing, but fails some couple hundred lines in... for no apparent reason.

Curious if anyone has seen this before and happens to know the fix? Would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Correction: The first code segment is actually encapsulated in some php that just gets caught by chrome as html tags. The full segment of code that I got back from my index page, is actually the entirety of a page that I require_once at some point. Un-parsed by the PHP interpreter.

Comment: Is the unparsed PHP code opened using `<?` as opposed to `<?php`?  This would mean `short_open_tag` is turned off in php.ini.

Comment: HAH! That is accurate sir. I'll give that a spin.

Comment: Nailed it. You should repost as an answer so you get credit ;)

Comment: Here's a question - anyone have a regular expression to find <?\r\n   ? Seems like <? gets parsed as something else. I dont really do regular expressions.

Comment: Glad tht was it, I just added an answer, and maybe some regex you could use to replace them in the files if you use `sed`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the issue may be that your PHP script uses [short tags](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) `<?` but the PHP configuration is such that it does not accept short tags and wants full tags `<?php`.

You can either change `php.ini` and set `short_open_tag` to `1` or modify the scripts to use the full open tag.  I would recommend using the full open tag as the short tags have problems with XML files with PHP extensions.

You will also want to check for short echo's, `<?=` and replace those with `<?php echo`.

Some regex you may try:

```
/<?([^p])/<?php$1/g
/<?= /<?php echo /g
```

Answer (score 2):

IIS and Apache are two different beasts. For you own sanity, strive to keep your development environment close to your deployment environment.

Comment: Sound advice, and thanks... But I'm not sure that it quite resolves my problem. :P